# How to use npm packages in Blazor JS modules?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can I use npm packages in blazor js modules?
I am using typescript and compiling it to js, but the imported modules do not get included.

Ex.

```
import {something} from 'some-lib-from-npm'

export function doMagic(input: string): void {
  something(input);
}
```

I have a working solution, using WebPack and bundling everything into a single JS file, but I would like to avoid that and use this feature instead.